# ReSharper's <reference path=""/> is not working with local paths

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, resharper, qunit

I'm trying to reference some libs in qunit tests. When I'm using Resharper's

```
/// <reference path="/Scripts/require.js" />
```

It produces the following reference in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="reference/~/../MyProjectFolder/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

So reference is broken. I've tried different ways to specify path like absolute path, relative path, tried to start path with '~' or '../' and everything works the same way.

I've also tried to use external CDN path, and it worked properly, but I need a way to link local files.

Update: I'm using Resharper 9.1.

Comment: What is the path of your test file and the reference file?

Comment: Test file: \Scripts\tests\mytestfile.js
Reference file: \Scripts\require.js
Or another reference file: \Scripts\tests\anotherReferenceFile.js

I know that Jasmine is not working with require.js but the problem here is not with it. I also tried to link any other js files from different locations.

Comment: It was a bug in ReSharper which is fixed in 9.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed in ReSharper 9.1.1!